# Find Quarter of DateTimePicker Selected Date

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker named `dtpDateSelection`.  When I select a date I need to break the date down into two variables.  I need `Quarter` to equal the quarter that the date is in.  And I need `Year` to equal the year that the date is in.  I thought I knew how to do this but I'm having trouble. Here is the code I've tried:

```
Dim Year As String = DatePart("yyyy", dtpDateSelection)
Dim Quarter As String = DatePart("q", dtpDateSelection)
```

And this is the error I get:

`Additional information: Argument 'DateValue' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
Dim year As Integer = DateTimePicker.Value.Year
Dim quarter As Integer = ((DateTimePicker.Value.Month - 1) \ 3) + 1
```

Comment: When I use your code I get two duplicate error messages.  The error messages say `Reference to a non-shared member requires and object reference`

Comment: Use `dtpDateSelection` or whatever you named the instance of your DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 1):

So you have the `DateTime` value from the `DateTimePicker.Value` property.

Using that you can retrieve the year of the date, like this:

```
Dim year As Integer = DateTimePicker.Value.Year
```

For determining the quarter the date is within, try this:

```
Public Shared Function DetermineQuarter(dateTime As DateTime) As Integer
    If dateTime.Month <= 3 Then
        Return 1
    End If

    If dateTime.Month <= 6 Then
        Return 2
    End If

    If dateTime.Month <= 9 Then
        Return 3
    End If

    Return 4
End Function
```

Now you can get the quarter value, like this:

```
Dim quarter As Integer = DetermineQuarter(DateTimePicker.Value)
```

Comment: Good solution, but why subtract 3 from the month?

Comment: @DouglasBarbin - changed logic to use a utility function instead of confusing, non-working modulus and integer division logic.

Comment: the modulus wasn't necessary, but you can do it with integer division.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, a DateTime value has a .Month member.  For the quarter, I have always used a simple Choose function

```
Dim quarter As Integer = Choose(DateTimePicker1.Value.Month, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)
```

Beyond that, your two lines of code work, but you need to add the .Value to the end of dtpDateSelection.  The DatePart function 2nd parameter has an Object type, so it will allow you to pass in a control (which is what you are doing), but the end result will be an error.  The .Value changes it to the date selected in the picker.

```
Dim Year As String = DatePart("yyyy", dtpDateSelection.Value)
Dim Quarter As String = DatePart("q", dtpDateSelection.Value)
```